# JSON API client to manage user accounts

Tags: javascript, promise, typescript

I have the following class in Typescript (using the Aurelia SPA-framework).

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework";
import {Apiclient} from "../services/apiclient";
import * as gravatarUrl from "gravatar-url";

// Dialogs
import {DialogService} from "aurelia-dialog";
import {RedigerBruker} from "./dialogs/rediger-bruker";

@inject(Apiclient, DialogService)
export class Brukere {
    users;
    lastFetchSuccess:boolean = true;

    constructor(private api:Apiclient, private dialog:DialogService) {

    }

    gravatar(email) {
        return gravatarUrl(email, { size: 48, default: "mm" });
    }

    activate() {
        return this.api.getUsers().then(
            res => {
                if(res.status == 200) {
                    res.resultObject.then(json => this.users = json);
                    this.lastFetchSuccess = true;
                } else {
                    this.lastFetchSuccess = false;
                };
            });
    }

    editUser(userId) {
        this.api.getUser(userId).then(
            res => {
                if(res.status == 200) {
                    res.resultObject.then(json => {
                        this.dialog.open({ viewModel: RedigerBruker, model: json })
                            .then(response => {
                                if (!response.wasCancelled) {
                                    console.log("MKS: Good - " + response.output);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("MKS: Bad");
                                }

                            });
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(`MKS: Error retrieving user ${userId}: ${res.status} - ${res.statusText}`);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This code works. The API-client is just a simple wrapper around the fetch-client that returns simplified objects with status, statustext and the JSON-result promise. If you look at the `editUser` function. This function takes a user-id, passes it to the api-client which fetches the data from the server, and then returns the result-object. This code looks like the usual callback-pyramid-of-doom. Which makes me think I'm not using promises correctly.

Am I completely fumbling the use of promises, or is this just the way it works and I have to deal with it? Maybe there is some other way to code this?

Comment: Code review titles should reflect what your code does, not your problem / what you are hoping to achieve from the review.  Please try to update your title to summarise what it is your code actually does.

Answer (score 1):

The promise just allows you to act when the asynchronous call has been completed. So all you need to do in your 'Then' is say what to do with the result when it is there. Nothing stops you from calling a nice function in there that handles the result. ;) You've got two functions in there at least: process the result of the GetUser call, and then open the Edit dialog. So split those out and things will start to look much better.